# SQL Server 2017 - High CPU usage after service start

Tags: ms-sql

For a long period now we have an issue after a reboot of the host OS or restart of SQL Server 2017 service that the `sqlservr.exe` process takes 100% CPU. It uses so much CPU it is almost impossible to logon to remote desktop. The only way recover the server is to enter a remote Powershell session and either kill the process or lower its priority.

Usually after letting the process run overnight the CPU usage stabilizes and then it is fully stable. Attempted to run a repair yielded no improvements. All five databases checksum fine. We use memory optimized tables in the databases if it matters. The databases are not larger than a few gigabytes.

There are other SQL Server instances (2012, 2016, 2019) which operate properly. How can I diagnose this high CPU usage issue?

Comment: I would question 1) what security product you have installed and are the proper exclusions in place? 2) Obtain a etl trace, e.g. `wpr.exe -start GeneralProfile` start the service to re-create the issue, leave for 30 seconds, then run: `wpr.exe -stop C:\gp.etl`.  Use Windows Performance Analyzer to analyze the trace file.

Comment: Except the default Windows Defender that comes with Windows Server 2019 there is nothing else installed.